# How to hide the label (CCLabel) after a certain time in cocos2d?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I added a label by using CCLabel to my layer. Now I want it do disappear after some time like (2sec). How can I make it to disappear?

```
CCLabel *labelPerfectDraw = [CCLabel labelWithString:@"Perfect Draw" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:30 ];
        labelPerfectDraw.color = ccc3(0x00, 0x00, 0xff);
        labelPerfectDraw.position = ccp(windowSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2+80);
        [self addChild:labelPerfectDraw];
```

I added label in above way.
Please give me the idea how can I work on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `visible` property for `CCLabel` instances as they are derived from `CCSprite`.  That should do it.  Just set it to false or rather you want it to disappear after 2 seconds so create a function attached to a timer which sets visibility to false.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Before the above solution, I have used the CCFadeOut to hide it and I have given the time for it to fade out. It worked. 
id actionLabel1 = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.5f];
[labelLateDraw runAction:actionLabel1];

Thank You again.

Comment: Ah ok.  I missed part of what you were saying.  Yes Fade Out works as well in that case.